# Purpose of client ID if hashed client secret can be used as a public identifier?

Tags: hash, oauth-2.0

In a web application that handles its own username and password persistence, asking for just a password at log-in time would be inadequate. This is because the password is relatively low entropy, meaning multiple users may have the same password. Adding the username as an additional factor increases security.

In other models where an API key is generated (such as [AWS](http://www.awslessons.com/2017/aws-api-gateway-adding-apikey-requests/)), only that key is required to authenticate. No username / public identifier is required because the API key itself is high entropy and practically unique. In communication with a database, a query might look like `select email_address from accounts where cryptographically_hashed_api_key = $1`.

The OAuth2 flow between a client and authorization server uses a [client secret](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/) for which:

> A great way to generate a secure secret is to use a cryptographically-secure library to generate a 256-bit value

making it secure enough to serve as a standalone key. Because it is practically impossible to guess, an attacker knowing the client ID is irrelevant.

Just like an API key is cryptographically hashed when put in a database (which when considering worst-case scenario is public data), **why can we not hash the high entropy client secret during the flow between a user frontend and client?** Using the hashed client secret (computed on demand from the client secret) as a public identifier for a client and getting rid of the client ID concept would remove an extra field to maintain in environment configuration without compromising security.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth has a concept of two types of client:

- Public clients (mobile apps, desktop apps, browser based apps) send only a Client ID to identify themselves. They cannot store and send a fixed application level client secret securely.
- Confidential clients (websites, SPA using back end for front end, mobile app using dynamic client registration) send both a Client ID and Client Secret to identify themselves. If the client secret applies to all users then it is only ever sent from back end components.

Note that both types of client also use the following security:

- An end user has to authenticate before an authorization code is issued
- The authorization code is returned on an attested URL that the application owns, such as an HTTPS domain
- The authorization code is swapped for tokens using at least a runtime secret (a PKCE code verifier), and preferably also a permanent client secret (which can involve use of Mutual TLS in some setups).

Removing client IDs or hashing client secrets would reduce flexibility and not improve security. Hopefully this gives you a flavour though, of how the two fields can be used in multiple ways for different use cases.